# SQL Server is not returning the correct decimal values when using CAST, just zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server newbie here. I'm trying to find the percentage of injuries (Injuries treated on scene) that each Bus Line was responsible for (operator). I want my result to include 2 decimal places but all I'm getting back is two zeros as decimals which I know mathmatically isn't correct. How do I get my result to show the correct decimal values?

*23158 is the total number of incidents

I've tried this:

```
SELECT operator, CAST(((COUNT(*)*100/23158) AS DECIMAL (10,2))
FROM LondonBusSafety
WHERE[Injury Result Description] = 'Injuries treated on scene'
GROUP BY operator
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

[My query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xaTw.png)

[My query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQjSc.png)

[Total number of 'on scene' injuries per bus line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmzdS.png)

Looking at Metroline for Example, (2610*100) / 23158 = 11.27

Why is my result returning 11.00 instead of 11.27?

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: Well what does `SELECT 100/23158;` give? Now try `SELECT 100.0/23158;`.

Comment: There's a difference between integer and floating point math. Your SELECT does integer math. Integers don't have decimal points or values to the right of that non-existent decimal point.

Comment: Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate explains this well (and why I suggested to try `*100.0` instead of `*100`.

Comment: Thank you so much @AaronBertrand. That makes perfect sense, I got my desired result and I'll keep that info handy from now on!

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite. I see what you're saying and will make those adjustments for the future.